# How to create dynamic uitextfiled inside a loop and make all them editable mode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am continuously facing problem to create uitextfield programmatically inside a loop and make all them in editable mode?

I have created successfully text fields inside the loop but problem is that. the last one i.e. the last text field is in editable mode.

EX:
suppose an array (myarray) has 5 values.

```
-(void)createDynamic_textfld{

    UITextField *roomratetxt;

    UIScrollView *scrlsummery;

    NSMutableArray *myarray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@[@"one",@"two",@"three",@"four",@"five"], nil];

    for (int i = 0; [myarray count]; i ++){

        roomratetxt = [[UITextField alloc]init];

        roomratetxt.frame = CGRectMake(200, 0, 90, 20);

        roomratetxt.textColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lighttextcolor.png"]];

        roomratetxt.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        roomratetxt.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];

        roomratetxt.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[myarray objectAtIndex:i]];

        roomratetxt.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

        [roomratetxt setTag:i];

        [roomratetxt setDelegate:(id)self];

        [scrlsummery addSubview:roomratetxt];

    }

}
```

i want to make all 5 textfields in editable mode. but as of now, the last textfield is only in editing mode and the rest all are non editable mode.

Can anyone plz suggest me some ideas ?How to achieve this

Thanks in advance.
Ajeet Kumar

Comment: you are using same frame for all textfield. This will overlap all textfield

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to provide different frames for that you can them in different position. Your above code looks correct and it must be in editable mode. I execute below snippet on my project and it works like a charm. I am assuming you are using Scrollview and added all textfield in it. Only thing make sure you are not disabling them from

> - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField; // return NO to disallow editing.

or

> - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
>     replacementString:(NSString *)string;   // return NO to not change
>     text

for (int i = 0; [myarray count]; i ++){

```
roomratetxt = [[UITextField alloc]init];

roomratetxt.frame = CGRectMake(200, i*20, 90, 20);

roomratetxt.textColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lighttextcolor.png"]];

roomratetxt.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

roomratetxt.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];

roomratetxt.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[myarray objectAtIndex:i]];

roomratetxt.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

[roomratetxt setTag:i];

[roomratetxt setDelegate:(id)self];

[scrlsummery addSubview:roomratetxt];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)createDynamic_textfld{

    UITextField *roomratetxt;

    UIScrollView *scrlsummery;

    NSMutableArray *myarray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@[@"one",@"two",@"three",@"four",@"five"], nil];

    for (int i = 0; [myarray count]; i ++){

        roomratetxt = [[UITextField alloc]init];

        roomratetxt.frame = CGRectMake(200, i*0, 90, 20);

        roomratetxt.textColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lighttextcolor.png"]];

        roomratetxt.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        roomratetxt.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];

        roomratetxt.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[myarray objectAtIndex:i]];

        roomratetxt.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

        [roomratetxt setTag:i];

        [roomratetxt setDelegate:(id)self];

        [scrlsummery addSubview:roomratetxt];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The frame of all 5 textField are putting in the same position. You might need to change their frame as well.

```
for (int i = 0; [myarray count]; i ++){

roomratetxt = [[UITextField alloc] init];

roomratetxt.frame = CGRectMake(200, i*60, 90, 20);

roomratetxt.textColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lighttextcolor.png"]];

roomratetxt.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

roomratetxt.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];

roomratetxt.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[myarray objectAtIndex:i]];

roomratetxt.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

[roomratetxt setTag:i];

[roomratetxt setDelegate:(id)self];

[scrlsummery addSubview:roomratetxt];

}
```